# Css Nav Menu Hover

Tags: css, colors, hover

so I created a nav menu using css and I'm having just one issue, when I hover over the sub-menu, I wish for the top-menu to change font color to white so people know which sub-menu they are viewing ...

```
<li style="width:150px" id="lovedating"><a href="#">Love & Dating</a>
<div id="love&dating" class="belownav">
<div class="ontop">Love & Dating</div>
<div class="navitem"><ul id="navitemul">
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/broken-hearths/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Broken-Hearths.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Broken Hearths</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/dating/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Dating.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Dating</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/dating-humor/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Dating-Humor.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">General Health</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/flirting/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Flirting.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Flirting</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/kissing/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Kissing.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Kissing</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/physical-relationships/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Physical-Relationships.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Physical Relationships</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/relationships/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/relationships.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Relationships</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/weddings/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/weddings.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Weddings</span></a></li>
</ul></div>
</div></li>
```

So I wish for the li#lovedating to be font-color white while I'm hovering over the sub-menu ul#navitemul. Is this possible with css only ... I tried:

```
ul#navitemul:hover li#lovedating a{color:white;}
```

But it has no effect, please advise :) Thank You

Please visit my site, www.curious-howto.com and view the menu if you wish to understand more what I'm saying :)

Comment: Not until css 4. You'd need a parent selector which will be part of css 4, but that's future.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be

```
<ul id="navitemul">
<li style="width:150px" id="lovedating"><a href="#">Love & Dating</a>
</li> <!-- Close the <li> tag here -->
```

Because your `<li>` tag include all of the `<div>` so the style will inherit

Answer (score 0):

I would try using jQuery.

```
$('ul#navitemul').hover(function(){ // change color of the link to white
       $(this).closest('#lovedating a').css('color', '#FFF');
  },function(){ // change the color of the link back
       $(this).closest('#lovedating a').css('color', '#009');
});
```